# Pass a String parameter to several threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a struct like this:

```rust
pub struct Connector {
    host: String,
    executor: ThreadPool,
}
```

This struct features a method, that dispatches work (TCP-connections) on several threads via `TcpStream::connect()`.
Unfortunately I got an error when referencing a field of a struct.

```rust
self.executor.execute(move || {
    if let Ok(_) = TcpStream::connect((self.host.as_str(), 8080)) {
        println!("Connection established");
        //...
    }
});
```

This code above leads to following error message:

```
std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::boxed::Box<(dyn threadpool::FnBox + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

I have also tried to make the `host`-field a `&'static str`, but since this is data from external input this does not work (I can't transform a `String`-object into a `'static str`).

How can I insert the struct's field into its threads as parameters?

Edit: Creating a new variable inside the scope leads to:

> creates a temporary which is freed while still in use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're not passing a `String` parameter; you're passing a `&str` parameter. Since you're effectively passing it to a different thread, the Rust compiler cannot check whether the reference will live long enough. Passing a `&'static str` would indeed have been a good solution if the string was actually static, but if that's not the case, you have to pass something that's owned.

In this case, the answer is somewhat complicated by the fact that `TcpStream::connect()` likely accepts a `T: ToSocketAddrs` and what works will depend on what impls exist for `ToSocketAddrs`. For example, tokio's `ToSocketAddrs` is [implemented](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.13/tokio/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html) for `(&'_ str, u16)` but not for `(String, u16)`. It is implemented for `String`, though, so perhaps the simplest solution here is to build a `String` and allow the closure to take ownership of that `String`, along these lines:

```rust
let addr = format!("{}:{}", &self.host, 8080);
self.executor.execute(move || {
    if let Ok(_) = TcpStream::connect(addr) {
        println!("Connection established");
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding `!format("{}:{}", self.host, 8080)` directly into the closure resulted in the same error,  but moving it into a variable above actually solved this problem.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I added a code sample to make that clearer. Does it match your code?

Comment: Yes, thats basically the same